# Where is "Run Tests" in monodevelop

Tags: c#, nunit, monodevelop

I have a solution already containing a library with NUnit tests. When I develop with Visual Studio, I normally run these tests with the nunit.exe binaries I have included in a `tools\nunit` folder in my project.

I'm now developing the same solution with monodevelop. I'm pretty sure I remember that there was an integrated "run tests" action in monodevelop, and I would like to use this to run the tests. According to [this article](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/using-nunit-with-monodevelop/) there should be a "View - Unit Tests" menu item. However, I must be doing something wrong/special because I can't find it.

How do I run my NUnit tests with Monodevelop?

Comment: Please check which MonoDevelop version are you running. 2.6 doesn't exist, the latest release is 2.4.1. Also, which operating system are you using?

Comment: @Lluis: I must have confused the version of Monodevelop with the version of Mono, I was pretty tired last night when I posted this question. The platform is Ubuntu 10.04 but I might have installed a more recent Monodevelop package from somewhere else, or perhaps even compiled from source. I'll check again later today and will provide more details.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu, make sure you have the MonoDevelop NUnit plugin installed through the package manager. Once you have it, click on "View -> Pads -> Unit Tests". The unit tests pad will be shown and then you can run test fixtures by double clicking on them.

Comment: all you need is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7570288/1115187, currently, it is a next answer)))

Answer (score 32):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop-nunit
```

Comment: The saddest thing:`Support for NUnit 3 was added in: Xamarin Studio 6.0.0.4514`

(from https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=35915)

I am on Linux Mint, and there still Monodevelop **5.x**

Answer (score 11):

To summarise the answers so far:

1. `sudo apt-get install monodevelop-nunit`
2. Select menu item: `View | Pads | Unit Tests`

Tested with clean installs of Ubuntu 12.04 and MonoDevelop 2.8.6.3.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall that there is a "run tests" action built-in mono develop. But there is an add-in you can use.

> **Enabling the NUnit Add-in**
>
> The NUnit addin requires mono 1.1.9+.
>   This is do to some cross-appdomain bug
>   fixes. Debian users currently also
>   have another particular problem in
>   that NUnit packages are separated from
>   Mono, and do not include the proper
>   pkg-config files.
>
> Configure monodevelop with the
>   following command.
>
> ```
> ./configure --enable-nunit
> ```
>
> **Debian users only**
>
> Install the nunit and libnunit-cil
>   packages (requires unstable at this
>   moment). Due to the separate packaging
>   of nunit, we need to make a symlink so
>   that monodevelop knows where to find
>   the pkg-config file.
>
> ```
> ln -s /usr/lib/pkgconfig/nunit.pc /usr/lib/pkgconfig/mono-nunit.pc
> ```

EDIT: I found some more info here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/NUnit_MonoDevelop.aspx. If it doesn't help, I might try it tomorrow on my mono develop, what platform are you using?